# Google+ data fetch redirect uri mismatch

Tags: android, servlets, google-api-java-client

I am developing an android application along with a  servlet running on tomcat 7.
 
The android app allows user to login via google, for this I am using google oauth 2.0
after logging in (in `onConnected()`) I am using `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...)` to get authorization code (at least thats what i think it is, correct me if wrong)

I am passing this code to a servlet running at `http://localhost:8443/MyServlet/MyServ`
At server I try to exchange this authorization code for **access_token** and **refresh_token**
but it always gives

> error : redirect_uri_mismatch

below is the servlet code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", CODE)); 
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "MY_SERVER_CLENT_ID"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "MY_SERVER_CLIENT_SECRET"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "`https://localhost:8443/Myservlet/Myserv`"));   
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
//Leave this line how it is 
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(post);
System.out.println("raw: " + response2.toString());
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response2.getEntity());
System.out.println("message " + responseBody); // That just logs it into logCat
```

[google console image](https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=0B19FnIHfhDQyZWpOazQwWEJhV2s&authuser=0&v=1419661607811&sz=w1275-h553)

The redirect uri is properly set still getting this error

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: ever solve this?  Can't see the google console image anymore.

Comment: No the the problem is still not solved,
  
sry for the link problem  ,

updated link: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B19FnIHfhDQyU0tOelVQTjFnb2c/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try using 'postmessage' as your redirect_uri.  I've found that using an actual redirect_uri only works if you are actually expecting google to do a redirect.  If not, they expect the value to be 'postmessage'.  It is not well documented at all.